# function not differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> find an example  of a  function  $f : \mathbb{R}^2  \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^3$  which has  all the   partial derivative  at $(0,0)$  but  not differentiable  at $(0,0)$

My attempt  :  i take  $f(x,y) = \cases {0,&if $(x,y,z)=(0,0)$\\
xy^2z^4/(x^2+y^4+z^6) &otherwise}$

Is  its  true ?

Comment: This is not a function to $\mathbb{R}^3$. What is $z$?

Comment: @PeldePinda  $z$  is  belong  $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: How do you define multiplication of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (because you talk about $z^3$)? I don't think you really understand what $\mathbb{R}^3$ is. For example, $f(x, y) = (x, y, 0)$ is a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @PeldePinda  u r  right   that  is my faults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider $$f(x,y) =\left(\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

In general, $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable iff each component function $f_i$, $1 \leq i \leq m$, is differentiable. Thus studying the differentiability of functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ more or less reduces to studying the differentiability of functions $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudents1122  How can  i know  that   whether this function  is differentiable  at  $0$ or  Not  ?

Comment: @jasmine As I said in my answer, you just need to check that $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ is not differentiable at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. This is fairly easy, since it's not even continuous at $(0,0)$. To check this, consider approaching the origin from the lines $x=y$ and $x=0$.